# How can I create bare repositories in atlassion-stash

Tags: git, bitbucket

We create bare repositories with following command on command line.

```
 git init --bare <path>
```

How can I create bare repositories in [atlassion-stash](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/server)/ (bitbucket server )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that a git "server" management tool like Atlassian Stash doesn't inherently create bare repositories -- having a checked-out working copy on the server doesn't make the least sense.

Maybe you're confusing "repository without a single commit" with "bare"?

*Bare* repositories are ones that don't have a *working copy* checked out.